# Aws::Transfer::TransferManager::UploadDirectory and content-type

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm attempting to use `Aws::Transfer::TransferManager::UploadDirectory` to upload a directory of files to s3.  These files will later be hosted via CloudFront to web clients.  For this reason, I need to set several headers such as Content-Type, Content-Encoding and they will be different depending on the file.

At first glance, there does not appear to be a way to specify this information when as part of the UploadDirectory call.  There is a for`Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::String>() metadata` that feels like it should be what I want, but it's missing documentation and I'm not sure how a string -> string mapping could do what I want.

Is `UploadDirectory` the wrong approach here?  Would I be better off re-implementing my own version so that I can do more per-file operations?

Comment: `2000 years later`... Looks like it is expected to put the headers in the metadata argument the usual way one would do when provided with std::map<std::string,std::string> - the key is the header name and the value, well, the header value. And of course you just could check the source.